# In GCP, few buckets are automatically get create with the name of artifacts?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In my storage buckets few buckets like "eu.(projectname).appspot.com" gets created. And if I see the data it contains /container/images/sha256:0009123f10d7bc2678777b0fd6d8b261fcfd2eba63b9385b05a1ab5c0492a90. Like this a lot of sha files are present. Can anybody know from where it gets created and what happens if I delete this bucket. Thanks

Comment: Do not delete those buckets. They are used by Google services such as App Engine, Cloud Build, Container Registry, Artifact Registry, etc. Review the documentation for each service.

Comment: It is taking a lot of data. Can I put retention period policy?

Comment: My advice is to leave those buckets alone. Others on Stackoverflow have mentioned disasters when they tried to reduce/manage that storage space.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will leave it alone